# CMake cannot find QWidgets

Tags: qt, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt file which looks like this:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
project(myApp)

# Set minimum version of CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Find Qt5Core and Qt5Widgets
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

# For finding Qt includes
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Collect source files
set(SOURCE
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
)

# Collect header files
set(HEADERS
    mainwindow.h
)

# Create executable
add_executable(prog ${SOURCE})

# Linking Editor with Qt libraries
target_link_libraries(prog Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)
```

When I run cmake and then make the following error message is presented;

```
Scanning dependencies of target Prog
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Prog.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /path/main.cpp:7:0:
/path/mainwindow.h:7:20: fatal error: QWidgets: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Where am I doing wrong with the CMake file?

`mainwindow.h` looks like this:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
/*
 * mainwindow.h
 */
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidgets>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidgets *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

};

#endif
```

Comment: Show your `mainwindow.h`. It seems like you have something like `#include <QWidgets>` in there, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: It should be `#include <QtWidgets>`.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: yes, that is what i have in mainwindow.h. What is wrong with that?

Comment: It should be #include <QWidget> and class MainWindow : public QMainWindow

Comment: @DavidMarquant: thank you very much it works. Please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
#include <QWidget> 

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

...
```